# Adding new text to textfile based on matching keyword (Python)

Tags: python

I want to read through a textfile until encountering a specific keyword.

Following that keyword, is a column of lines with names + value ending with a '/'.

I want to write a new keyword after the column of names (it ends with a single row/line with a '/'). And IF one or more of the name matches the names I have in a dictionary - write the name with corresponding value from the dictionary and end with /.

After all matching names are written, it should end with a '/' on a line below, just as the previous keyword.

There are hundreds of occurrences of the keyword in the text file, so this new keyword + information should be added below the keyword every time its reached. But the names and values added depends on what names matches the ones under keyword.

Structure of text file:

KEYWORD

A_1   10      /

A_2   100     /

/

Want to add this below:

KEYWORD2

A_1  62 /

/

based on input_dict = {A_1:62}

In the real case, a lot more names are specified under KEYWORD1 and in input_dict.

Idea of implementation that hasn't worked:

```
with open('filename', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('KEYWORD'):  
            for line in f: #starts at keyword
                for key in input_list:
                    if line[0] == key:
                        #add key value pair from input_list to temporary dictionary.
                    elif line[0] == '/'
                        break
                    #write to file: newline, then key-value from temp-list ending with '/', then newline etc. Should end with a single line of '/'
    #continue looping through lines until next instance of keyword is found.
f.close()
```

Comment: U have written `for line in f:` inside `for line in f:`

Comment: The idea of that is to start a loop going through the text from that point until 
 a line only containing '/' is reached. But as this is a little above my level in Python, I was not able to produce a working code for the problem